# Given two arrays how to get items that are not in both?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, relational-algebra

I have two arrays in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 
declare 
        first integer[];
        second integer[];
        array_vb integer[];
        array_vb2 integer[];  
begin

    code.... 

    select array_agg(id) into first
    from a
    where id = any (array_vb);

    select array_agg(id) into second
    from a
    where id = any (array_vb2);

end;
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I would like to add a `raise notice` that will print all items that are in first but not in second

for example:

```
first = [1,10,15,3,7]

second = [1,3,15,4]
```

it will print `10,7`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL [unsent](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(first) EXCEPT SELECT unnest(second))
```

Example:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,10,15,3,7]) EXCEPT SELECT unnest(array[1,3,15,4]))
```

Gives:

```
array
--------
{10,7}
```

See SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5028).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`intarray` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html):

```
create extension if not exists intarray;

select array[1,10,15,3,7] - array[1,3,15,4] as result;

 result 
--------
 {7,10}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function f(a1 int[], a2 int[])
returns void as $body$ 
begin

    raise notice '%', (
        select string_agg(i::text, ',')
        from
            unnest (a1) a1(i)
            left join
            unnest (a2) a2(i) using (i)
        where a2.i is null
    );

end;
$body$ language plpgsql volatile
;
select f(array [1,10,15,3,7], array [1,3,15,4]);
NOTICE:  10,7
 f 
---

(1 row)
```

Notice that the above function, as it is, can be marked `immutable`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns the desired array result:

```
create or replace function array_except(a1 int[], a2 int[])
  returns int[]
as
$$
    select array_agg(i)
    from ( 
      select i
      from unnest(a1) i
      except 
      select a2
      from unnest(a2) a2
    ) t;
$$ 
language sql;
```

The function returns an array that contains the elements that are in the first, but not in the second array.

You can use the above function in your actual function:

```
create or replace function foo()
  returns void
as
$BODY$
declare 
  _first integer[];
  _second integer[];
begin

    _first := array[1,10,15,3,7];
    _second := array[1,3,15,4];
    raise notice 'Result %', array_except(_first, _second);

end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```